# Win32 API VS C++; Text Box Content to String

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, textbox

I am new with programming Win32 applications. I have programmed a text box where the user can enter text. The problem is that I don't know how to get the input of the box into a string, which is necessary to process the input. For testing purposes, I tried to give out the entered text through the output text box, which I had to program anyway.

Googling, I found out that `GetWindowTextA(hInput, input, length);` should do the trick. However, I am not sure how to get the input into a variable using this method.

So, my question is, how do I get a text, entered by a user into a text box, into a string?

In case this does matter: I am not using the free version of Visual Studio, as I have free access to Microsoft software through my university. And at the moment I am using Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate Preview anyway. To answer the question in advance, this is NO homework or other work for my university, for a job or anything commercially. I have taught myself C++, which has become my favorite programming language, and I want to be able to program graphical interfaces with it.

Here is Visual Studio's standard code with some modifications, most notably the addition of two text boxes and a button (which does nothing at the moment and is of no importance for this question):

#### Includes, globals, forward declarations

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WilliTeX.h"
#include <iostream>;

using namespace std;

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

//custom defines
#define TEXT_INPUT_BOX 1
#define TEXT_OUTPUT_BOX 2
#define BUTTON 3

HWND hInput;
HWND hOutput;
HWND hButton;

int length;
LPSTR input;

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name


// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

#### _tWinMain

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_WILLITEX, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WILLITEX));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

#### MyRegisterClass

```
//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_WILLITEX));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WILLITEX);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}
```

#### Rest of Code

```
//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        //This is the input box, where the user enters the text
        hInput = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            "EDIT",
            "",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            50, //moving left/right the box
            10, //moving up/down the box
            1300, //length
            350, //height
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)TEXT_INPUT_BOX,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);

        //This is the output text box, that will display the convertion
        hInput = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            "Edit", 
            "test",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            50, //moving left/right the box
            200, //moving up/down the box
            1300, //length
            450, //height
            hWnd, 
            (HMENU)TEXT_INPUT_BOX,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);

        hButton = CreateWindowExA(NULL,
            "BUTTON",
            "OK",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            3, //moving left/right
            10, //moving up/down
            48, //length
            50, //height
            hWnd,
            (HMENU) BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);

        break;
    }
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);

        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
            //refreshing the output box whenever the user is giving an input
        case TEXT_INPUT_BOX:
        {
            length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hInput);
            GetWindowTextA(hInput, input, length);

            hInput = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "Edit",
                input,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50, //moving left/right the box
                200, //moving up/down the box
                1300, //length
                450, //height
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)TEXT_INPUT_BOX,
                GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                NULL);

            break;
        }

        case BUTTON:
        {
            break;
        }
        }

        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

P.S. I am aware that using namespace std; is bad coding practice but for this learning program I don't really care.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating the input text box (again) when you get a message from it. That doesn't make sense. ANd your GetWindowTextA call is using a variable 'input' that you have not defined. Allocate a character array for that variable.

Comment: LPSTR input; I have globally defined the variable as I originally used it in more than one place. The problem is that the variable input does not contain the user input or something else is wrong. If I would do this: input = "Test", the second text box would show "Test" as soon as I start typing something into text box 1.

Comment: LPSTR input defines a pointer. That does not assign any memory for it to point to.  You must have some memory to pass to Windows. If it is global then start with char input[1024];

Comment: Using char input[1024] has the effect that I delete one letter after the next of the word test but I don't write anything. Apart from that, does char* also work? I would hate having to use an (normal) array, as this would mean that I would have to guess how long the input will, especially with long inputs being very likely.

Comment: Apart from my current implementation, isn't there some method that would allow me to store the content of the text box in a variable, preferably string or char*?

Comment: Not automatically like that. You will need to get the length of the text in the edit control using the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message or the `GetWindowTextLength()` function, allocate a buffer large enough to store that text, and then call `GetWindowText()` to get the window text. Also is there any reason you are using the ANSI (`A`) variants of the functions and messages, and not the Unicode (`W`) variants?

Comment: @Willi Of course you can store the content in a variable. A char array is a variable. Allocate it as a fixed size as I showed you or a dynamic size as andlabs explained. But you can't store text in a char*, that's just a pointer to a char array that has to be allocated.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out with the length. I already had it in the code for an other try but forgot about it at first. The reason I used the A variant is that the simple version, used in some tutorials and in a book, didn't work for me, so I tried them out to find the one working for me and that was A. I assume the W version will work as well. Using char input[1024]; char input[length] or whatever didn't work. I also rewrote the code so that pressing the button what cause the update in case that has been the problem.

Comment: The problem is that length is worthless to me, as arrays will not work with non const variables and int length needn't be declared as const int length. The program should be able to update length regularily and there shouldn't be any artificial length limit which will only cause me trouble. The program should work with an one-word input or a 1.000-page novel if needed. So I guess I will have to look for another way of getting that input. Mabey I'll have to change that method.

Comment: The Windows API functions use C types, not C++ types. The answer by andlabs explains how to use length to create a dynamic array that is large enough. After you have that much working you can, if you like, copy that temporary array into a std::vector or std::string that will provide more convenient C++ features. By choosing to program at the Win32 level you are working at a very low level but wishing for higher level flexibility.

Comment: The problem is, I am trying to port an application to C++, I originally programmed in Java, to have the additional features of C++. I know from using that program, that I sometimes enter only 20 characters, sometimes 5 pages worth of text. As I probably won't have access to the Windows API, to add my custom method, I will have to think about a workaround. Mabey I should look if Qt or another Win32 alternative is programmed in a more modern style.

Comment: Workarounds would be too much unnecessary work, especially because I would have to consider that someone is changing already written text afterwards (e.g typing errors), so storing char[] in a vector would have to be a two-way road. With 8 GB RAM, using a ridiculously large array shouldn't hurt that much and it doesn't after a test.

Comment: So I simply use the characters count including spacings of a 139 large Word document to ensure that I will never every reach this artificial limit. char input[341898]; With that, my original question has been answered. But if someone has a better alternative for arrays, I would still be interested in hearing it as I have always hated to implement artificial limits to my programmes as they only cause me trouble afterwards.